# Can't figure out how to prevent HTTP caching in Chrome using cache-control

Tags: google-chrome, cache-control, no-cache

I'm having some trouble trying to prevent my page from caching using the cache-control parameters in the HTML header. Below is a sample HTML code which I've created for testing purposes. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing though, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding how all this cache-control really works. I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
</head>
<body>
    Test Html
</body>
</html>
```

I apologize for the link, but I'm not allowed to post pictures yet. When I view "chrome://cache", I see the cached page in the list of cached items. Clicking on it, I am able to view the actual content itself.

[Chrome's cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7hn3.png)

From my understanding, using the no-cache or no-store should prevent the page from appearing in Chrome's cache. Is this assumption correct?

Thanks in advance.

Heng

Comment: possible duplicate of [is meta http-equiv value cache control is not supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824848/is-meta-http-equiv-value-cache-control-is-not-supported)